# localhost is currently unable to handle this request HTTP ERROR 500 in Codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost, mamp

I use MAMP for MAC and I had a project on my local. It worked well. I decided to update this project and downloaded from my web server after what localhost shows 500 error.

[image]

However, when I enter another localhost projects, it works. I use Codeigniter3 framework. Where can be the problem?

Comment: Check your error logs

Comment: where can I check them?

Comment: Sometimes I use a technique where I use php's `die` to see if I can get to a point in code execution. For instance, if I use `die('X')`, and I get "X" on my screen, I know I haven't reached the problem, so I advance by a few lines of code and test again. You'll eventually reach a point where you know where the problem is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CodeIgniter in the `index.php` file has options for different environments `production` and `development` and supports having subdirectories of the same name in the `config` folder with different configs depending on the environment. My guess is that the first line of the `index.php` file says this `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');` and points to a production database in `/application/config/production/database.php` (as you downloaded it from a production server) - and as a result you can't connect nor are you getting any errors as by default the production environment serves no errors just a 500 page if something went wrong.

If you don't have different subdirectories for production and development than you just have one `config.php` and one `database.php` file in the main `config` directory. Change the `database.php` to reflect your local development databasename, password, .etc. and change the environment define to development `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`.

At the very least you should begin to get errors by changing to development.

Otherwise its a more complex problem to locate.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked! But, can you please explain the difference between `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');` and `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` ?

Comment: You can see the primary difference in the `index.php` file right below this. Essentially `production` silences errors (so as to not give users an idea of your internal framework opening you up to attacks) and `development` doesn't - allowing you to see all errors.

Comment: Something I do is have a local `index.php` with development and a remote `index.php` with production as environment. This way, you push all files except for `index.php` and with your /production and /development subfolder configs you can be sure wherever you are using your site it works and you don't have to fiddle around with one config changing the variables back and fourth. (if that makes any sense)

Answer (score 0):

For me I have been using the `127.0.0.1` it was giving the error but, I am trying it using `localhost`, it's working properly.